# JBuilder + OJ slow json rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, performance, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am rendering to json an array of records and their eager-loaded associations.

Using

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(ActiveRecord::Base) {|x| 1+1}
```

I get 165 instances, thus my jbuilder views take **1 second to render 165 records into 69K of json**.

I'm already using OJ as the JSON backend.

I have no experience at all with rails and json rendering performance.

I would like to know if such speed is the expected performance, which I hardly believe, or if the problem lies in my jbuilder views, and thus a solution lies ahead on my path.

EDIT:

With yajl takes a few ms longer than with oj.
The first time, it takes 1 second to render, while next requests take ~0.5s (I guess that **jbuilder does some caching on its own by default**).

**However 0.5s is way too much for me, as index requests will involve more than 165 records.**

Comment: yajl is recommended for fast rendering, see the github repo. Btw, maybe you dont include relationships and waste time with db calls

Comment: Hi, I do include the associations; plus rails server tells me it took 1 second to render and 0.142s for ActiveRecord activity. MultiJSON chooses OJ over yajl by default, so I'll give it a try, but I doubt it will change anythin

Comment: You may wan't to look at [Fast JSON API](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi). In my experience it has always been at least twice as fast. [Others](https://medium.com/nugit-engineering/blazing-fast-rails-view-rendering-15c7f52c1cfa) have even better results.